# Exposing fields in Unity Editor - Range not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is a snippet of my code. I want the floats to show up as range bars that I can drag to change in the Inspector.

They just show up as boxes I can write in. How do I get them to show up as range bars?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] [Range(0f, 100f)]
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0f, 100f)]
    public float jumpSpeed = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0f, 100f)]
    public float jumpVelocityCut = 5f;

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0f, 100f)]
    public float RayCastLength = 1f;

    //Ground Check
    private bool isGrounded = true;

    //Ability unlocks
    private bool isDoubleJumpUnlocked = false;
    private bool isWallRunUnlocked = false;
    private bool isDashUnlocked = false;
    private bool isRefreshUnlocked = false;

    //Ability uses
    private bool isDoubleJumpUsed = true;
    private bool isWallRunUsed = true;
    private bool isDashUsed = true;
    private bool isRefreshUsed = true;

    Rigidbody2D rb;
   
      //Other code continues on here
    
}
```

Images included

[How they currently look in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIov0.png)
[How I expect them to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Negr.png)

I tried following a [tutorial](https://unity3d.college/2017/05/22/unity-attributes/) and I don't see what I'm doing differently.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[SerializeField]` attribute?

Comment: When I remove the [SerializeField] attribute nothing changes.

Comment: are you sure it compiled? and which version of unity is this?

Comment: As written, it doesn't compile. There is an extra `}`. So depending on what the "other code" is it may or may not actually compile.

Comment: Yes, it compiles. when I was erasing a bunch of the extra code for the post I just missed an extra "}". 

It is in unity 2021.3.31f1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the root cause was but I turned off my computer at night and when I went back to it the next day the inspector view was in the correct range as I was expecting.

Comment: This follow-up observation should be appended to the original question, since it is not an answer or solution to the problem, but an additional piece of data as to the source of the problem. If you restarted your computer and the problem went away, that doesn't mean the solution is restarting the computer — unless you can reliably reproduce the problem and resolve it by restarting the computer. It just means there may have been something temporary, cached, or in the system memory that was creating the problem.